# Silent Install of Haskell Platform

Tags: windows, haskell, installation, platform, silent

I'm trying to deploy Haskell platform to 3 University labs. Although the installer is only 90mb the extracted Haskell is almost 1gb. I've repackaged, but its still too big. Are there any command line arguments that can be used with HaskellPlatform-2011.2.0.1-setup.exe so I can script the install?

Thanks

Comment: Why is 1gb too big? (And how is the size relevant to scripting the install?)

Comment: Hi Chris. We're limited on space on our file server so I do want to store the repackaged application at 1gb, but instead only store the 90mb installer there. I cannot seem to find any command line switches that will let me script the install. Do you know of any, ie HaskellPlatform-2011.2.0.1-setup.exe /silent

Comment: Can you just push out a trivial program that mounts a network drive with the 1GB thing on it and runs it from the network drive?

Comment: Yes, I can mount the application but again I don't want to store 1GB on the file server if I don't have to. For our purposes, and limited storage, it makes more sense to store the 90mb on the file server and expand on the local workstations during a silent installation. Hence the need for install switches.

Answer (score 5):

According to the [Windows Haskell Platform](http://trac.haskell.org/haskell-platform/wiki/Windows) page, the installer uses NSIS.

From the [NSIS documentation](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter3.html#3.2):

- `/S` runs the installer silently
- `/D=foo` sets the installation directory
- `/NCRC` disables the CRC check

Comment: I tried the install again and saw that it was packaged using Nullsoft. Since Nullsoft uses the /S switch for silent installs I was able to use:
HaskellPlatform-2011.2.0.1-setup.exe /S